# mongoid group_by return a hashmap instead of array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to retrieve a hashmap from a mongoid group_by instead of a array

```
Product.group_by {|p| p.user_id }
```

returns an array of mappings

```
result = Product.group_by {|p| p.user_id } 

=> [ {"12354asdf" => [product1, product2, product3]},
{"safakjgh314" => [product4, product5, product6]} ]
```

I'm currently running the result of this query over the following to achieve a single hash of mappings

```
result.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

> => {"12354asdf" => [product1, product2, product3],
>       "safakjgh314" => [product4, product5, product6]}

is there a more efficient way to do this?

edit***
After grouping I'd rather operate over the collection with an enumerable that makes sense.

```
result.each do |k v| k v end
```

rather than

```
result.each do |h| h.keys.first, h.values.first end
```

example of what it currently returns.

```
[ 
  {user_object => [item1, item2, item3] },
  {user2_object => [item1, item2, item3] },
  {user2_object => [item1, item2, item3] }
]
```

Comment: The method here essentially implements the [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) method from the MongoDB API. The results are returned as an array by design. Even operations like `findOne` esstially just wrap standard methods just as your code does.

Comment: How would you want it to be more efficient?

Comment: formatted funky I added comment to original question

Comment: You already have the answer, what else do you need? Sorry, I'm trying to understand...

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the more compact way to iterate over the array of hashes, you can take each element's `first`:

```
result.map(&:first).each do |k, v|
  puts k
  puts v.count
end
# 12354asdf
# 3
# safakjgh314
# 3
```

Comment: I'm liking this. Does this iterate over the array twice or once?

Comment: I did not know you can iterate over a array with .each with more than one block argument...

[["a","b","c"]].each { |array_element_1, array_element_2, array_element_3| p array_element_1; p array_element_2; p array_element_3; }

Comment: is it efficient to call .map(&:first) versus using .reduce(Hash.new, :merge)?

Comment: @StephenNguyen - yes it does iterate the array twice. You could use lazy enumerables to force it to iterate once (http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/) but the performance overhead is much higher than anything you might gain in this use-case. I can't definitely say my solution is _more_ efficient than `merge` (I think in general arrays are more memory efficient than hashes, and both have a `O(n)` time complexity), but it is _as_ efficient as the `merge` solution, more succinct and a _lot_ more ruby-style.